# How to format a string matrix into x rows and y columns

Tags: java, string, arraylist, replace, format

I have a string variable that stores gets the values of an ArrayList using toString().

```
 matrixOne = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>>();

 String output = matrixOne.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
```

Output prints the following values:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, i, h, g
```

**I want them to be formatted within the toString() method to format into their actual rows and columns on new lines with a tab between the values. Example:**

**3 by 3:**

```
a  b  c
d  e  f 
i  h  g
```

**Note: The row column needs to be changeable by changing `row` and `column` variables i.e.**

so `output` is now: `a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, , n, o, p`

**2 by 3:**

```
a  b  c  d  e  f  g  i
j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q
```

Actual Method

```
public String toString() {

     String output = matrixOne.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");     
         return output;
    }
```

Comment: By doing `new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>>();`, you get the structure `[[[value, value], [value, value]], [[value, value], [value, value]]]`. How do you find rows and columns in that? Shouldn't you use two dimensional `ArrayList` instead of three?

Comment: Rows and Columns are determine when the matrix object is created in constructor..  public Matrix(int rows, int columns) {
  this.rows = rows;
  this.columns = columns;
  
   matrixOne = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>>();    
   for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) { 
    matrixOne.add(new ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>());
    
    for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++) { 
    matrixOne.get(i).add(new ArrayList<T>()); 
    }
   } 

 }

Comment: I'm working on your case, tell me, the values ​​you pass as a string always ?, or is your list a string?

Comment: Actually the value that is passed is through a method (the type is actually generic <T>:  public void insert(int row, int column, T value) {
  matrixOne.get(row).get(column).add( value);
 }

Comment: And as example;  nums.insert(0, 0, "a");
      nums.insert(0, 1, "b");
      nums.insert(0, 2, "c");

Comment: The rows and columns are created in the constructor (code in question section)

Comment: any ideas pleasee?

Comment: @Shaz Well, more or less I understand what you want to do, let me see what I can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this can help

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0, rowCount = matrixOne.size(); i < rowCount; i++) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> row = matrixOne.get(i);
    sb.append(row.toString()
        .replaceAll("\\[\\[|\\]|,|\\[|\\]\\]", "")
        .replace(" ", "\t"));
    sb.append("\n");
}
return sb.toString();
```

Comment: matrixOne.get(i); is an error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> to ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>

Comment: Its a multi array list remember i.e. matrixOne

Comment: Its working! Just more thing though, you haven't added the tab after each row, then its perfect! ideas ?

Comment: currently each values are separated by a space? you want a tab instead ?

Comment: OK. added `.replace(" ", "\t")`  :)

Answer (score 0):

**Ok, I have created a method that formats your string in a matrix where you can specify the rows and columns:**

```
public String toString() 
{
    String output = matrixOne.toString().replaceAll("\\[\\[|\\]|,|\\[|\\]\\]", "");     
    return FormatMatrix(output, rows, columns);
}
```

---

```
 public static String FormatMatrix(String str, int rows, int columns) {
 try {
  String[][] matrix = new String[rows][columns];
  String[] arr = str.split("\\s*,\\s*");

  int k = 0;
  int s = arr.length;

  for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
   for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
    matrix[i][j] = (k < s) ? arr[k] : "*";
    ++k;
   }
  }

  String append = "", result;

  for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
   append += "|\t";
   for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
    append += matrix[i][j] + "\t";
   }
   append += "|\n";
  }
  result = append;
  return result;

 } catch (Exception e) {
  return null;
 }
}
```